# Has the optimal learning speed been studied?

Tags: learning

My question is whether learning at "supernatural" speeds has been studied, in particular in relation to content retention and what are some research papers on this topic.

To clarify, one example of this would be watching lectures on youtube at 2x the 
regular speed.

My hypothesis (as someone completely external to psychology!)  is that there is an improvement, for the following reasons:

- there's no time to be distracted since there are no gaps in the presentation
- the voice of the teacher sounds very robotic and non-human, which helps to stay alert
- It just *feels* like taking a shortcut, so one is much more willing to put up with a 5min of videos rather than the original 10m.

  - I think this has to with the fact that they are shorter than the origianls. If the videos were 5' each to begin with this point would be nullified.

Comment: This isn't a bad question in itself. It has a very testable hypothesis, which is whether speeding videos/audio can be beneficial for learning. However, framing specifically in your personal experience makes it off-topic for this site. Would you mind editing it to make it a general question?